# How Can I test jQuery validation error msgs with cucumber?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I googled around and I found this:
https://gist.github.com/1056822

However, once I put it into my project I got this:

```
Unable to find xpath <XPath::Union:0x106cfc928 @expressions=[

<XPath::Expression::Where:0x106d026c0 @left=#<XPath::Expression::Where:0x106d02bc0 @left=

<XPath::Expression::Descendant:0x106d1e960 @left=., @expressions=[

<XPath::Expression::Literal:0x106d02d50 @expression=:input>, 

<XPath::Expression::Literal:0x106d02d28 @expression=:textarea>..... and it goes on
```

Can anyone tell me how jQuery validation is supposed to be test with cucumber?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just looking for the error messages...I believe the syntax is

```
Then I should see "<your error message text>"
```

Comment: I tried it out. But it does not work at all. For some reason the err mag never got rendered onto the source of my html. Have you ever succeed with just 'Then I should see "<your error message text>"'?

Comment: I got the problem solved according to your suggestion. Thank you. There was one more reason I could not see the error msg: the minify feature forgot to count in 'cucumber' environment.

Answer (score 1):

As jaydel said, you can just use `Then I should see "whatever".`

If you want to use XPath, try checking out W3School's XPath page: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

You should only really be using XPath if you want to dig deep in to the DOM and do very specific stuff that simply doing `I should see` doesn't support.

You can also try looking up Capybara's rdoc (http://rdoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/frames) if you want to write something custom.

Comment: The dependency gotta be 'Capybara', because webrat does not inherently support javascript, right?

Comment: should I add @javascript above?

Comment: I've never used webrat, but I believe you are right. You only need the `@javascript` before the scenario if you know that the scenario you are testing will fire off some javascript, in which case the browser needs to be open to run it. You do not need `@javascript` if you just want to use XPath.